Windows form size is not the same after publish
I am developing a windows form application with c# language on visual studio. I am using the Devexpress infrastructure.
After changing my computer, I installed the same versions of Visual Studio and DevExpress on my new computer to avoid any problems with my applications.
My old computer's screen was running at 1920:1080 resolution and 100% screen scale. My new computer is running at 3120x2080 resolution and 200% screen scale.
When I open the applications on my new computer, they do not scale automatically. The images on the buttons are smaller than they should be, the forms do not fit in the area they should be and appear smaller.
I am also sending sample images as attachments. The first image is the image of the form while it is running in the background. Everything looks correct. The second image is the image after publishing the application. I tried the published application on different computers, but they all have the same problem.
1. Form on visual studio 
2. Form after publish

did you anchor your controls to the bottom winodw?

I am using MDI Parent form. But this is not a problem before

This might be helpful: https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/116666/common-features/high-dpi-support?utm_source=SupportCenter&utm_medium=website&utm_campaign=docs-feedback&utm_content=T682326

I find my solution anymore.
The final solution I ended with is using "unaware" instead of "PerMonitorV2"
In the app.manifest file
<application xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
<windowsSettings>
  <dpiAwareness xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2016/WindowsSettings">unaware</dpiAwareness>
</windowsSettings>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
